# observing the outlook events via Microsoft Graph

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I would like to observe the Office 365 Outlook calendar events by using Microsoft Graph. I created a client instance with the [@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client) package and know how to fetch events from a specific user

```
const usersResponse: any = await client.api('/users').get();
const allUsers: any[] = usersResponse.value;
const firstUser: any = allUsers[0];
const firstUserId = firstUser.id;
const userEvents = await client.api(`/users/${firstUserId}/calendar/events`).get();
```

What I basically want to do is to fetch every event that was created, edited or deleted but not for a specific user. Of course I could fetch all users and fetch all events from them but then I would have to observe the users too because some might get added or deleted.

I want to listen to all "company" events in realtime. I think polling every X seconds would be a bad approach. I'm looking for events I can subsribe to like

- `calendar.on('init', eventsFromNow => {});`
- `calendar.on('eventCreated', event => {});`
- `calendar.on('eventEdited', event => {});`
- `calendar.on('eventDeleted', event => {});`

Is there something I can use for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a supported scenario.

More importantly, consider what this would look like at scale. What you're asking for is active monitoring of every evert, for every user and group, across an entire organization. The computational cost of monitoring like this would be staggering.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My company is a very small organization, so I would like to try it out ... Would I have to poll for the users, groups and their events every X seconds?

Comment: You would have to write your own polling logic and handle the `429` throttling issues yourself.